# Unable to update child node in .json file using JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I have one .json file and I want to change child node value.
In below file, I  want to change country code from NZ to DE

```
{
  "@type": "Template",
  "matches": {
     "countryCode": "NZ",
     "partner": "JD",
     "packageId": "TEST",
     "userGroup": "small",
     "templateName": "rec"
  }
```

I have tried with following, but it not updates child node value. Can you please help in in doing this.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
public  JSONObject readJsonFile(String CountryCode) throws IOException, ParseException 
    {
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/TemplatesJSONPayload/" +"templates.json";
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);

        jsonObject.put("countryCode", "DE");
    return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: try something like jsonObject.getJSONObject("matches").put("countryCode", "DE");

Comment: Thanks @Shubham It's working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing value in parent node you need to get child node object then you have to change the value of countryCode.

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public  JSONObject readJsonFile(String CountryCode)throws IOException,ParseException
{
String filePath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/TemplatesJSONPayload/"+"templates.json";
FileReader reader=new FileReader(filePath);
JSONParser jsonParser=new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONObject matches=(JSONObject)jsonObject.get("matches");
matches.put("countryCode","DE");
return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `matches` object first and put in it,

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("matches").put("countryCode", "DE");
```